# I want to get A field Values let say (Name) From Data Table in C# Mvc,

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is My Code Please Have a Look. I want to get a Particular Field Values let say Name How can i get it? The method i used is not working

```
//DataTable result = new DataTable();
//Use Csv Reader to Read Data
using (CsvReader read = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(stream), true))
{
    //Load Data into Data tables
    result.Load(read);                           
}
foreach (DataRow r in result.Rows)
{
    string name = r[1].ToString();
}
```

Comment: have you tried `r["name"].ToString();`

Comment: In what way is it not working ? Do you have some small sample input ? Maybe you want r[0].ToString() ?

Comment: Thanks A lot for the suggestions, Its is working fine now, I was showing a single field that why its was not showing the value. But successfully inserted into db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you can directly use `DataRow["Name"]`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is an example:

```
foreach (DataRow r in result.Rows)
{
    string row_name = r["Name"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Got it Bro, Its is working Fine now, I have Got another problem, How to  check for Blank row in Data table?

Comment: Something along this could work:: `var is_empty = r.ItemArray.All(c => c == null);`

Comment: Can i use it Before Getting Row Elements ?

Comment: No, the `r` is a `DataRow`. But you can directly have a `foreach (var r in result.Rows.Where(r ->!r.ItemArray.All(c => c == null))` clause.

Comment: Thanks, bro let me try this ,  I hope it it will work :)